# Delete a dictionary based on the value of a key in another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries and a main dictionary.
List of dictionaries have the following format. Values are assigned a variable that changes dynamically in the program.

```
list_dict = [{'url': url_value , 'title' : title_value}, {'url': url_value , 'title' : title_value}]

main_dict = {"execution_time": "2017-06-05", "target_url": "http://www.bloomberg.com", "data": [{ "url" : url1}, { "url" : url2}], "name": "Michael", "occupation": "software"}
```

If any url value(url1 or url2) under data in main_dict is the same value as the url_value in any of the dictionaries in list_dict, I want to delete that dictionary from the data.

Output: Assuming url_value is url1 then:

```
main_dict = {"execution_time": "2017-06-05", "target_url": "http://www.bloomberg.com", "data": [{ "url" : url2}], "name": "Michael", "occupation": "software"}
```

I thought about using dict comprehensions, however everything I tried did not work. I would appreciate a starting point or any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> list_dict = [{'url': "url1" , 'title' : "title_value1"}, {'url': "other_url" , 'title' : "title_value2"}]
>>> main_dict = {"execution_time": "2017-06-05", "target_url": "http://www.bloomberg.com", "data": [{ "url" : "url1"}, { "url" : "url2"}], "name": "Michael", "occupation": "software"}
>>> S = set(d["url"] for d in list_dict)
>>> main_dict["data"] = [d for d in main_dict["data"] if d["url"] not in S]
>>> main_dict
{'execution_time': '2017-06-05', 'target_url': 'http://www.bloomberg.com', 'data': [{'url': 'url2'}], 'name': 'Michael', 'occupation': 'software'}
```

Instead of deleting elements of `main_dict["data"]`, the idea is to recreate the list without the matchings urls:

- extract the distinct urls of the `list_dict` in `S`;
- filter the dicts `d` in `main_dict["data"]` on the rule: `d["url"] not in S`.

Note on naming: try to name your variables according to the *content* and not the *type*.

- `list_dict` is a list of dictionaries (I can see it), but I would like to know immediately what's in those dictionaries. `web_pages` would be better, if you accept that an url + a title makes a page. But you should specify why those pages are on this list (e.g. `dead_link_pages`, or whatever)
- `main_dict` is a dictionary (pretty obvious and not really informative): something like `task` is better. Again, a better specification is informative: `update_task`, `retrieve_task`, ?
- ok, I replace `S` by `page_urls`!

Have a look, this is far more readable:

```
>>> web_pages = [{'url': "url1" , 'title' : "title_value1"}, {'url': "other_url" , 'title' : "title_value2"}]
>>> task = {"execution_time": "2017-06-05", "target_url": "http://www.bloomberg.com", "data": [{ "url" : "url1"}, { "url" : "url2"}], "name": "Michael", "occupation": "software"}
>>> page_urls = set(p["url"] for p in web_pages)
>>> task["data"] = [t for t in task["data"] if t["url"] not in page_urls]
>>> task
{'execution_time': '2017-06-05', 'target_url': 'http://www.bloomberg.com', 'data': [{'url': 'url2'}], 'name': 'Michael', 'occupation': 'software'}
```